# Custom component for Label with Text box and image in GWT

Tags: gwt

I need to create a custom component which can have Label then Textfield and Image, by clicking the image i should select date, that selected date should be populated in TextField,

Is there way i can develop a custom component.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely!

You need to create a custom widget, and the way to do that is to extend the Composite class.

From the documentation:

> A composite is a specialized widget that can contain another component (typically, a Panel) but behaves as if it were its contained widget. You can easily combine groups of existing widgets into a composite that is itself a reusable widget. Some of the UI components provided in GWT are composites: for example, the TabPanel (a composite of a TabBar and a DeckPanel) and the SuggestBox.
>   Rather than create complex widgets by subclassing Panel or another Widget type, it's better to create a composite because a composite usually wants to control which methods are publicly accessible without exposing those methods that it would inherit from its Panel superclass.

There is a good example to get you started here:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets.html

Answer (score 1):

The GWT showcase give an example of somthing similar to what you are looking for along with the source code:

["Date Picker" - GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDatePicker)

If you want to develop a custom component, look at @Jon Vaughan's answer!

Answer (score 1):

You may also use third party libraries with widgets, like [Ext GWT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/) or [SmartGWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/). Date picker is one of the base widgets that everyone provides.